# How do I go about putting uCLinux on a cortex M7?

Tags: linux, cortex-m

I would like to be able to run uCLinux on a cortex M7 board, but don't know where to start. I've searched the net and found a video demo of somebody who got it to work but no tutorials or anything.

Comment: Why?  That's probably not a great idea in this day and age.  Unlike in its era, chips with a full MMU are quite cheap today - enough RAM to make it *useful* is the main complication, and uCLinux needs *more* RAM rather than less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get Linux or uCLinux to run on a bare board is a difficult task. It is a process called "porting" and needs a lot of skill, experience and patience. Rather than do the porting yourself you should look for a board where someone has already  ported a suitable version of uCLinux. This collection of software is called a Board Support Package (BSP), and there will be a BSP that runs on the target board without modification. Also, there should be a guide to help you modify and build the BSP so you can customize it to your own requirements. For embedded Linux the BSP is usually built on another Linux machine, I presume the its the same with uCLinux.

I did a search for "uclinux bsp for cortex m7" and found quite a few listed, although some you will have to pay for. This one [here](https://www.emcraft.com/stm32f7-discovery-board) is for the STM32F7 Discovery board which has a Cortex M7 processor.